# Searching at bibliographyc list (prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have this prolog code:

```
libro(autor('Chomsky', 'Noah'),
      titulo('Aspectos de la Teoría de la sintaxis'),
      editorial('Madrid', 'Aguilar'),
      fecha(1970)).

libro(autor('Matthews', 'P'),
      titulo('Inflectional Morphology'),
      editorial('Cambridge', 'Cambridge University Press'),
      fecha(1972)).

libro(autor('Chomsky', 'Noah'),
      titulo('Estructuras sintácticas'),
      editorial('Mexico', 'Siglo XXI'),
      fecha(1974)).
```

I need to find all books written by Chomsky (in my case). What is the rutine to obtain them?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to match on the pattern `autor('Chomsky',_)` as below:

```
?- libro(autor('Chomsky',_),T,E,Y).
T = titulo('Aspectos de la Teoría de la sintaxis'),
E = editorial('Madrid', 'Aguilar'),
Y = fecha(1970) ;
T = titulo('Estructuras sintácticas'),
E = editorial('Mexico', 'Siglo XXI'),
Y = fecha(1974).
```

You need to type a semicolon to fetch the next result.

You could also use `findall` to get all results as a list, for example:

```
?- findall(libro(T,E,Y),libro(autor('Chomsky',_),T,E,Y),R).
R = [libro(titulo('Aspectos de la Teoría de la sintaxis'), editorial('Madrid', 'Aguilar'), fecha(1970)), libro(titulo('Estructuras sintácticas'), editorial('Mexico', 'Siglo XXI'), fecha(1974))].
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this question. It was helpful